# getting this error while running flutter app on chrome

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run my app on Chrome but I'm getting these errors. Also installed windows visual c++ update but still not working
f5:

```
Unable to launch browser : spawn unknown 
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Flutter run -d chrome :

```
CreateProcessW failed 14001

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "ProcessException: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

  Command: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  --user-data-dir=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.282fd59e\flutter_tools_chrome_device.1c0b2e2a --remote-debugging-port=1636
  --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check
  --disable-default-apps --disable-translate http://localhost:1573".
A crash report has been written to D:\LaughBit\laughbit\flutter_06.log.
This crash may already be reported. Check GitHub for similar crashes.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ProcessException%3A+The+application+has+failed+to+start+because+its+side-by-side+configuration+is+incorrect.+Please+see+the+application+event+log+or+use+the+command-line+sxstrace.exe+tool+for+more+detail.%0D%0A%0A++Command%3A+C%3A%5CUsers%5Cabc%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CGoogle%5CChrome%5CApplication%5Cchrome.exe+--user-data-dir%3DC%3A%5CUsers%5Cabc%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CTemp%5Cflutter_tools.282fd59e%5Cflutter_tools_chrome_device.1c0b2e2a+--remote-debugging-port%3D1636+--disable-background-timer-throttling+--disable-extensions+--disable-popup-blocking+--bwsi+--no-first-run+--no-default-browser-check+--disable-default-apps+--disable-translate+http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1573

To report your crash to the Flutter team, first read the guide to filing a bug.
https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/bug-reports

Create a new GitHub issue by pasting this link into your browser and completing the issue template. Thank you!
https://git.io/JOSer
```

Comment: Hi, Anyone can help me with this  ????

Comment: Still Having it

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Chrome File location, let say on Windows 10/11, or even in a `shortcut icon -> Right-click -> Properties -> Open File Location`.

You will see two applications of the chrome: chrome.exe and chrome_new.exe.
Run the chrome_new.exe and it will delete and replace the previous chrome.exe.

After that, you will now be able to start and use Google Chrome again.